# Run maven test not in default src/test/java folder

Tags: unit-testing, maven

I have a project containing `pom.xml` and some `JUnit` tests. Both `pom.xml` and unit tests are corrects. But problem is that tests are not in src/test/java folder (I cannot use this folder). Is it possible to tell maven to execute tests from another source folder (which is also in this project)?

Comment: in another source folder - src/int-test/java

Comment: I'm sure you have great reasons why you can't use src/test/java.  So I'm only going to ask "why?" because nobody has answered your question so far.  (Maybe the answer will provide more insight.)  One of the first things I learned about Maven was that you really should adapt to its conventions because it's just painful if you don't.  That's the whole idea of "configuration vs. convention."

Comment: Are these tests really unit tests? Based on the name of the folder i assume these tests are integration tests. If this is true you shouldn't use maven-surefire-plugin for such purposes. Better is to use maven-failsafe-plugin for such integration-tests.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is enough to add this part to your pom:

```xml
<project>
    ...
    <build>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/int-test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    </build>
    ...
</project>
```

The test sources will be compiled during the `test-compile` phase and the `maven-surefire-plugin` will find the test classes too.

Comment: Under maven 3.6.2 this results in the following error: `[ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs: Malformed POM ....../pom.xml: Unrecognised tag: 'testSourceDirectory' (position: START_TAG seen ...<build><testSourceDirectory>`.