# In Maven is it possible to keep integration tests in a separate folder from unit tests?

Tags: maven, integration-testing, maven-failsafe-plugin

On the [Maven and Integration Testing](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Maven+and+Integration+Testing) page it says:

> The Future Rumor has it that a future version of Maven will support
>   something like src/it/java in the integration-test phase, in addition
>   to src/test/java in the test phase.

but that was back in 2011-12-11. Has this happened yet?

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13258882/254477) to ["Run maven test not in default src/test/java folder"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257987/run-maven-test-not-in-default-src-test-java-folder) it mentions setting the `<testSourceDirectory>`, is their some way of doing this just  for integration test (ie. the `integration-test` phase)?

I'm looking to use the [Maven FailSafe plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) and avoid renaming a bunch of integration tests or using the still experimental JUnit `@Categories`.

Comment: Here is another answer that is up to date with latest maven: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46831999/maven-add-integration-tests

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can put the IT'ss into different folder like this:

```
.
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    |-- it
    |   `-- java
    |       `-- com
    |           `-- soebes
    |               `-- maui
    |                   `-- it
    |                       `-- BitMaskIT.java
    |-- main
    |   `-- java
    |       `-- com
    |           `-- soebes
    |               `-- maui
    |                   `-- it
    |                       `-- BitMask.java
    `-- test
        `-- java
            `-- com
                `-- soebes
                    `-- maui
                        `-- it
                            `-- BitMaskTest.java
```

The following is needed to make then folders known to the compiler etc.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.5</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>add-test-source</id>
      <phase>process-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>add-test-source</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <sources>
          <source>src/it/java</source>
        </sources>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

The following is needed to really run the IT's:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.15</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>integration-test</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>integration-test</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>verify</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>verify</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

This means you can have the integration within the same module which has the disadvantage that running the integration tests use the same resources as the unit tests. A better solution would be to create a separate maven module where you can put the integration tests into the usual folder `src/test/java` etc. and only configure the maven-failsafe-plugin.

Comment: Nice! Just to be clear both test and it will be scanned for unit tests and integration tests so it will fundamentally still depend on the filename to distinguish between the two right?

Comment: For the first scenario correct. But the better is having a different module where you can change the naming convention. I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: Why does the failsafe plugin run during `<phase>verify</phase>` instead of `<phase>integration-test</phase>`?  It seems odd for failsafe to run after `<phase>post-integration-test</phase>`?

Comment: It looks like the same `build-helper-maven-plugin` invocation can be used with `<goal>add-test-resource</goal>` to add `src/it/resources` to the list of test resources directories.

Comment: @khmarbaise In your first example, I understand putting `BitMaskIT` into a package named `com.soebes.maui.it` but not `BitMaskTest` and `BitMask`. I would expect those classes to be in a class called `com.soebes.maui`, right?

Comment: @mattalxndr You can do of course. But the package name shouldn't be a criteria. Best is to make a separate module for IT's.

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm not implying that it would change the results, but in the example, you might as well put `BitMask` and `BitMaskTest` classes in the most likely package, right? The fact that they are in the `.it` package leads me to wonder if they need to be, since it doesn't make sense why they would be.

Comment: Ah sorry. misunderstanding on my site. You can of course put the IT's in a package what ever you like. I just wanted to make clear that they are not in the same package as the unit tests cause IT's should have access to package private classes.

Comment: @khmarbaise I have both groovy test and java tests in a module named `integrationtests`. When I run `mvn test` or `mvn verify` it only runs java tests while groovy (spock) tests are also compiled in test-classes. why is that? I am using both fail-safe and surefire plugin like above.

Comment: Rather than adding test sources in the ```process-resources``` phase, wouldn't it make more sense to do it in the ```generate-test-sources``` phase?

Comment: you saved the day my friend. thank you kindly