# How do I mark a folder as a test folder in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have two test directories in my java project. One contains integration tests and another unit tests:

```
── src
│   ├── it
│   │   └── java
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   └── resources
│   └── test
│       └── java
```

I'm using the `failsafe` plugin to run these integration tests. To register the `src/it/java` directory as a testing source I'm using the `build-helper-maven-plugin` plugin. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17866387/11550924 for the full setup.

It works fine from the command line - running `mvn verify` successfully executes my integration tests.

However in Eclipse I get import warnings on all classes that are scoped as `test` (e.g. junit) in the integration test classes.

It must be that Eclipse isn't recognising this folder as one which contains tests.

Does anyone know how to tell Eclipse that this folder is a testing folder?

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the failsafe plugin - eg, as described here : https://www.baeldung.com/maven-integration-test

Comment: @racraman I am using the failsafe plugin. The link to the setup shows what's in my pom.xml. I'll clarify in the question.

Comment: Great - but then all tests can live under src/test , and it’s the naming of the tests that differentiate unit tests from integration tests.   You could always have the integration tests under a new src/test/it .

Comment: I could, sure. But this is all working from the command line. I just want to know how to make it work in Eclipse.

Comment: I think Eclipse maven plugin is only recognizing files under `src/test` as tests. Is there any specific reason for creating `it/java` parallel to `test/java` ? Any reasons or constraints for not keeping all tests together under same hierarchy. Something like `src/test/java/it` & `src/test/java/ut`. We can also use Tags & Profiles to decide which are executed by default in maven build.

Comment: @Arkantos it's just a habit I have from a previous Scala project. We were using a different IDE though so maybe that's why the issue didn't arise.

I like the separation of integration and unit tests into different directories. I suppose I could just put try in the hierarchy you've suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to IntelliJ and this folder structure worked fine.

If you can't do that just put the integration tests under `src/test/java/it`.